# Unable to configure project reports in TFS 2010

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I'm trying to use team foundation server power tools to add project reports to an existing team foundation server 2010 install. Here's the command I'm running with the output...

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>
>   tfpt addprojectreports /c ollection:https://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/Projects /teamproject:SANDBOX / processtemplate:"MSF for CMMI Process Improvement v5.0" /validate
>
> **The project collection does not have reporting configured.  Therefore,
>   reports cannot be added to projects in the collection.**

The error message seems to indicate that reporting services has not been set up for the whole project collection. If I log into the TFS server and run the TFS admin console, hit Reporting under the application tier, each area (warehouse, analysis services and report server) indicate that everything is configured and enabled.

Also, if I point a browser to the report server configured within the admin console I get a directory listing with two data sources listed (Tfs2010OlapReportDS, Tfs2010ReportDS) and a directory called TfsReports. In the TfsReports dir there is a Projects directory and further a directory within the projects directory which contains what I'm assuming are the default reports for a project. If I drill all the way down to an actual report Build -> Build Summary, it runs just fine.

So, it seems like reports are configured for one of the team projects, but I'm not sure how this was accomplished since I'm not able to do this for other projects. If I run the previous command and use the name of the project that already has reports for it, I get the same error message.

I don't think I have the collection URL incorrect because if I totally fudge this I get a TF31002 error indicating unable to connect to TFS.

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TFS Administration console, go to the project collection and in the Reports Folder tab ensure that you have set the Default Folder Location.

If the tab isn't showing (because you haven't closed the admin console since you configured reporting), click the refresh button at the top of the window and it should appear.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Richard! Such a simple solution, I'm surprised I didn't see that this field wasn't set before. You saved me a whole lot of hair pulling and wasted time, thanks again.